# extracting data from xml file with php code

Tags: php, xml

**I have an xml file containing data like below but I am doing a test run to see whether I can extract all the data. However I have trouble in getting the imgpath values.**

```
<datas>
  <projects> 
    <project>
      <projectlogopath>logo1.gif</projectlogopath>
      <groupname>group1</groupname>
      <imgtitle>Company1</imgtitle>
      <images>
        <imgpath>comp1_sc01.jpg</imgpath>
        <imgpath>comp1_sc02.jpg</imgpath>
        <imgpath>comp1_sc03.jpg</imgpath>
      </images>
    </project>
    <project>
      <projectlogopath>logo2.gif</projectlogopath>
      <groupname>group2</groupname>
      <imgtitle>Company2</imgtitle>
      <images>
        <imgpath>comp2_sc01.jpg</imgpath>
      </images>
    </project>
  </projects>
</datas>
```

**This is what I wrote in php read the xml file**

```
foreach($xml->children() as $projects){
    foreach($projects->children() as $project => $data){
        echo $data->projectlogopath;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $data->groupname;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $data->imgtitle;
        echo "<br />";

        foreach($data->images->children() as $data2) {
            echo $data2->imgpath;
            echo "<br />";
        }      
        echo "***<br />";
    }
}
```

**My result looks like this. What have I done wrong? Thanks a lot**

```
logo1.gif
group1
Company1



***
logo2.gif
group2
Company2

***
```

Comment: the output you've got is exactly what your code does. so what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your expected result is but try this changes:

```
foreach($data->images->children() as $imgpath=>$data2) {
            echo $data2;
            echo "<br />";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But I don't understand why it works for echo $data2; and not echo $data2->imgpath;

Comment: It will be more clear if I re-write the foreach loop as
        foreach($data->images->children() as $imgpath)  {
            echo $imgpath;
            echo "<br />";
        }